# Keep track of the last template function called

Tags: c++, templates

Currently:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void init(Args&&... args);

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void run(Args&&... args);

...

// init() must be called before run()
// init() only needs to be called again if T or args change, e.g.

init<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);
run<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);
run<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);

init<MyClass2>(arg3, arg4, arg5);
run<MyClass2>(arg3, arg4, arg5);
run<MyClass2>(arg3, arg4, arg5);
run<MyClass2>(arg3, arg4, arg5);

init<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);
run<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);
...
// I do not know the order of these calls at compile time
```

I would like to create a wrapper that handles init() for me, e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void runAndInit(Args&&... args) {
    if (T or args different from the last call) {
        init<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    run<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
...
runAndInit<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);
runAndInit<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);

runAndInit<MyClass2>(arg3, arg4, arg5);
runAndInit<MyClass2>(arg3, arg4, arg5);
runAndInit<MyClass2>(arg3, arg4, arg5);

runAndInit<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);
...
```

Is this possible? I would prefer a C++11 solution, but would accept later versions if necessary.

Comment: This question is very unclear. What is the purpose of the init function? I don't understand if it's an XY problem

Comment: with run can be used any class or a subset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every template instantiation is its own function. So you can just use a static function-scope variable:

```
bool mustReInit(int const* curr) {
  static int const* last = nullptr;
  return std::exchange(last,curr) != curr;
}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void runAndInit(Args&&... args) {
  static int const identifier{}; // different for each instance
  if (mustReInit(&identifier)) {
    init<T>(args...); // do not forward here!
  }
  run<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```